# What is the another way of to express "in the amount of"?

Tags: synonyms

What is the another way of to express "in the amount of"?

Especially while use in the money case

ie. I spend my money out of my pocket in the amount of 100 dollars.

Comment: It would be very helpful for you to provide an example of what you're trying to say.  For example, there isn't a better way to say "He wrote a check in the amount of two-thousand dollars."  But there may be a better way to say, "He lost a great deal of the company's money, in the amount of millions."

Comment: @JBH I think I put it under the wrong tag

Comment: I understood you were looking for a synonym, but the idom "in the amount of" usually has a specific (almost legal) usage.  To help you discover a useful synonym, we need to understand how you are using the idom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK we use '(in or to) the sum of' more than 'in the amount of'.  For example on bank notes it says "I promise to pay the bearer the sum of" and I have seen cheques (yes that's British spelling!) with 'The sum of' printed on them.

So in your example you might say

> I spent the sum of £100 out of my own pocket

However, certainly in speech it's now rare to use this phrase and normally you would just say

> I spent £100 out of my own pocket

As per James K's answer.

Confusingly, you *could* also use the word 'some' (meaning a non specific amount) to specify the amount, for example:

> I spent some £100 out of my own pocket

Although 'in the amount of' and 'in the sum of' are usually interchangeble, when there are multiple items which together total the amount in question it seems more natural (to me at least) to use 'the sum of'.

Answer (score 1):

> I spent $100 out of my own pocket.

The idiom "out of my own pocket" is a metaphor, it means that you weren't spending (for example) the company's money. So you don't need "my money". I've also put it in the past tense (which is more likely than the present)

In the example given the simplest way is just to use the amount of money as the object of "spend" (or pay, give etc.)

You can also use amounts of money like adjectives "$100 check" (do checks still exist?)

So "He wrote a check in the amount of $100" could become "He wrote a $100 check."